# How much time does it take to go from Frankfurt airport to the the city centre?

Tags: europe, airport-transfer, frankfurt

I have a transfer in Frankfurt. I will have five hours between flights. Will that be enough to visit the city center? And what should I use to get to the city center?

Comment: Whether 5 hours are enough or depends on your flights - do you pass border control? Collect and check-in your luggage? Are you allowed to exit the transit area at all?

Answer (score 1):

Approx. 20 minutes from the airport train stations plus waiting time (less than 15 minutes).

You can take any train in the direction of Frankfurt Hauptbahnhof.

[Further reading](https://www.frankfurt-airport.com/en/travel/transport.detail.suffix.html/article/travel/directions/local-public-transportation.html#public).

Comment: Make sure you're going Frankfurt/Main and not Frankfurt/Hahn ...